# DSN-less ODBC connections to SQL Server using PHP on RHEL

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

Is it possible to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using PHP and a DSN-less connection on RHEL?

Content of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

PHP Code

```
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=server_ip_here;Database=database_here;User Id=username_here;PWD=password_here";
$con = odbc_connect($dsn,$duser,$dpas) or die(odbc_errormsg() );
```

Error:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in /path/to/file/index.php on line 152 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Double checked my connection string here:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

PHP's odbc_connect can accept a DSN-less connection strings:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

> The database source name for the connection. Alternatively, a DSN-less
>   connection string can be used.

PHP Info confirms that ODBC is loaded.

```
ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    unixODBC
ODBC_INCLUDE    -I/usr/include
ODBC_LFLAGS     -L/usr/lib64
ODBC_LIBS   -lodbc

Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited
```

When doing an strace, it shows that `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/home/me/odbc.ini` gets accessed during the rendering of the page.  I did launch the page through the CLI to get these:

```
open("/etc/odbcinst.ini", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/home/me/.odbcinst.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The unfortunate fact is that all of this works if I use a DSN. I really need for DSN-less to work however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use DSNless connections to MS SQL Server from PHP.

Change "Driver" to DRIVER in your connection string.

Run odbcinst -j to check where your system drivers file is located then ensure it has the driver in it.

If I repeat what you did in Perl I get:

```
perl -MDBI -le 'my $x = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server}");'

DBI connect('Driver={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server}','',...) failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at -e line 1.
perl -MDBI -le 'my $x = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server}");'

DBI connect('DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server}','',...) failed: [unixODBC][Easysoft][SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]General error: server name not specified (SQL-HY000) at -e line 1.
```

Notice the first one fails like you get and the second finds the driver but I did not specify a servername so it basically demonstrates you need DRIVER.

Comment: It works! That is the most ridiculous thing I have ever heard. I would have never thought of trying something like this. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find the ODBC spec says DRIVER not Driver or driver but glad you are running now.